# Apollo Server wrapped Resolvers

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, resolver

A request to Apollo Server with default settings works directly, but not when wrapped in "viewer". Does "viewer" need a custom resolver and how does this resolver know to return from "nextUp" resolver?

```
query {
    nextUp(limit: $limit, eventTypes: $eventTypes) {
        eventKey
        eventType
        distanceMetres
        eventDateTime
        status
        __typename
    }
}
```

above returns valid data structure for nextUp.

below returns *null* for nextUp.

```
query {
    viewer {              # <----------- viewer wrapping nextUp
        nextUp(limit: $limit, eventTypes: $eventTypes) {
            eventKey
            eventType
            distanceMetres
            eventDateTime
            status
            __typename
        }
    }
}
```

typeDefs:

```
const typeDefs = gql`
    type Event {
        eventKey: String
        eventType: String
        distanceMetres: String
        eventDateTime: DateTime!
        status: String
    }
    type ViewerModel {
        nextUp(
            eventTypes: [String] = null
            limit: Int = 0
        ): [Event]
    }

    type Query {
        viewer: ViewerModel
        nextUp(
            eventTypes: [String] = null
            limit: Int = 0
        ): [Event]
    }
`;
```

and resolvers:

```
const nextUp= async (_source: any, _args: IGetNextUpAsync, { dataSources }: any) => {
    return dataSources.RestDataSource.getNextUpAsync(_args)
};

const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        viewer: async (_source: any, _args: any, { dataSources }: any, info: any) => {
            return nextUp;      // ???
        },

        nextToGo,
    }
};
```

Comment: Apollo Server works with whatever schema you provide it. Fields like `viewer` and `nextUp` are specific to your schema. Without seeing your typeDefs and resolvers, it's impossible to answer any questions about why fields are being resolved a certain way.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRearden. Have added the types & resolver sections. Does this make more sense now?